# shortcode_atts not parsing custom values instead defaults loaded

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I' making my own shortcode function and while the call of the shortcode works, and my page query within returns results - it never uses any settings but the defaults as if $att is null.

```php
    function test_shortcode( $atts ) {
       $filter = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'type' => 'major',
                'sort' => 'name',
                'size' => 'large',
                'links' => 'yes',
            ),
            $atts,
            'customshortcode'
        );

      echo 'ATTS:';
      print_r($atts);

      echo'FILTER';
      print_r($filter);

    //code to query posts removed

    }

    add_shortcode( 'customshortcode', 'test_shortcode' );
```

In the post I can then add..

```php
    [customshortcode type:"other" size:"small" sort:"rand" links:"no"]
```

To see the result

```
ATTS
Array
(
    [0] => type:"other"
    [1] => size:"small"
    [2] => sort:"rand"
    [3] => links:"no"
)
FILTER
Array
(
    [type] => major
    [sort] => name
    [size] => large
    [links] => yes
)
```

and I can see the $atts values are received in the function but the $filter is not updated. I'm expecting both arrays to be the same at the point they are being printed out. As far as I can tell I'm following the coxed formatting here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts

Comment: You are passing attributes in the wrong way. It should use `=`. Please go through https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/ to know more about shortcode with parameters. 

Try with `[customshortcode type="other" size="small" sort="rand" links="no"]`

Comment: OK yes that seems obvious now you pointed it out, I spent so long looking at the function and not seeing the way it was being called. I feel stupid for not seeing that. I can't see how to mark this comment as the 'solution' though.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing attributes in the wrong way.

It should use `=` instead of `:`.

Please go through https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/ to know more about shortcode with parameters.

Try with `[customshortcode type="other" size="small" sort="rand" links="no"]`